# Vue change key itself with v-model

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2

am a bit stuck now and cant find anything about it.

I have an json something like:

```
rows: {
    someKeyName: 'test'
}
```

Now I want to change the 'someKeyName' to 'myNewKeyName'.

I started with this

```
<section class="row" v-for="(value, key) in rows">
    <input type="text" v-model="........."/> <-- change key itself.. how...
    <input type="text" v-model="rows[key]"/> <-- change value of the key
</section>
```

But am stuck at the 'change key itself' part. I hope I explained what I mean, thanks for readin this! hope someone can help me

Comment: Not clear what asking

Answer (score 1):

You cant change the key itself with v-model. Copy Map into an Array and then edit the copy, and once done, clear the map and add the key/vals again.

Example:

```
{ '101':'Clark', '102','Stephanie' }
```

copy to a new array

```
[ {id: '101', name:'Clark'}, {id: '102', name:'Stephanie'} ]
```

Then, you can use v-model to edit this array.

When user clicks save, or on lost-focus you can copy values back into the map/object/dictionary.

Comment: I already thought of that, also made it, but i hoped for a simpler solution. Thanks for the reply confirming it it not possible.

Comment: Yes. As far as I know, it can't be done. As the key is the identity of the row. And changing the key would probably confuse Vue as to which is the first row now. Maybe someone has a shorter way ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

> you can try:

```
<section class="row" v-for="(value, key) in rows" :key="key">
    <input type="text" v-model="inputValue" @input="userInput(key)" />
</section>

data() {
    return {
        inputValue: '',
        rows: {
            a: 12
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    userInput(key) {
        // here you change the rows key
    }
}
```

Comment: thats the value for the key, not the key itself... and this way it is not even changing the value inside the rows object

Comment: cant do that, you can bind eventListener or use Array

Comment: Can you  show me some code for changing the key name?

Comment: <section class="row" v-for="(value, key) in rows" :key="key">
        <input type="text" v-model="inputValue" @input="userInput(key)" />
 </section>
       inputValue: '',
       rows: {
                a: 12
         } methods: {
        userInput(key) {
            // here you change the rows key
        }
    }

Comment: thats just giving me an event, thats not what i am looking for.

Comment: am asking for changing the key itself. thats the part that you are missing in your examples....